# Solution with dynamically assets in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm starting learn unity not long ago. Now, I have issues. When I build a game, I don't want build all assets in project. I want download some assets when Client after install game (Ex : first load Splashscreen). I tried to search and found `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload`. I don't sure it correct!.

Can you give me solutions or keyword?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on correct road. But i think you need to google a bit deeply the keyword and you would have reached the "Asset Bundles".

[Asset Bundle Defination](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

[Scripting Asset bundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DownloadingAssetBundles.html)

[Asset Bundle management](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingAssetBundles.html)

[Asset Bundle detail description](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager)

I did asset bundle usage quite some time ago so i might miss something while explaining this.

First you need to build the resources which you will be required.(Each platform has different builds so you need to keep that also in mind)

You will need a script to download and cache the asset bundle from the net.

> WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload

After caching comes the part of loading and unloading asset bundle from cache/resources. Also for every update we pushed we allowed application to check for any asset bundles were available so that it could fetch and use it.

I think there are some more helper scripts for the asset bundles and tutorials to go with on the net as I had used a script to generate asset bundles 
to modify it.

[Here is unity asset store Example and scripts for asset bundles](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45836)

So basically it will be a long solution to implement but it is worth every time you spend.

Hope this helps.

> Edit : Here is script I had used to create asset bundles. [Unifycommunity Asset bundle builder Link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/BuildAssetBundlesFromDirectory)

Comment: First for all, Thank you for reply and I have found solution with my issue :).  I build asset bundle and upload to server, use WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload to load it :). It work well